# Text associated with checkbox clicked, yet box is not checked/unchecked

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, label

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="chkId" checked='false' name="photoID" />
<label for="chkId"><asp:Literal ID="litPhotoRemove" runat="server" /></label>
</div>
```

The label is associated with the check box. When I click on the label, the checkbox should be checked.
Why is that, it is not checked?
Is there a workaround?

Comment: are you using javascript?jquery?show your code too

Comment: No, none associated with this control.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the text property of the asp.net checkbox control in order for the click to work smoothly. There are other ways, but that's how its done easily.

```
<asp:checkbox run at="server" id="whatever" text="Remove" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the check box inside the label. That way it will be checked when the label is clicked. You also get the benefit of being able to click the white space in between

```html
 <label for="chkId">
    <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="chkId" checked='false' name="photoID" />
    Remove Photo <!-- this would be your literal -->
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following in aspx to make it work.

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="chkId"  name="photoID" />
    <label for="chkId">
        <asp:Literal ID="litPhotoRemove" runat="server" Text="Remove"/></label>
</div>
```

You are missing `Text` of `asp:Literal`.

After making this change, if you view source of aspx in browser, it will be like following.

```html
<div>
  <input name="chkId" type="checkbox" id="chkId" />
  <label for="chkId">
    Remove</label>
</div>
```